Visual Studio 2022 v17.10 broke the build of BOOST. How to rollback to earlier Version?
I am so far out of luck to dial down the installed components (MSVC v143, etc.) to resemble a v17.9 installation. BOOST (and CMake) refuse to find the toolchain now that I removed the v17.10 tools. Is there a proper way to reduce the installation to that prior point?
Also see here: https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/914

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers will let you download older versions. I think the Enterprise or even Pro will allow you to select Community. I had to do this at work because I needed to get all development machines to have the same exact version of msvc installed.

Oops that was for 2019 which is what I use primarily. Here is the 2022 version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#fixed-version-bootstrappers

Did you try the patch from the link you provided - https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/914#issuecomment-2159445304

@RichardCritten the underlying issue has been addressed in B2 in a less introduce way (that didn't affect auto linking) as well (de bouton replies)
